# Firebase DB Rules + Authentication Not Working

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I can't seem to get my database rules to work, when they require authentication.

The user is logged in using JavaScript, and then the database is updated via PHP / REST request using [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php).

PHP:

```
$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib('https://AppNameGoesHere.firebaseio.com/');

$data = array(
   'field1' => $response_array['field1'],
   'field2' => $response_array['field2'],
   'field3' => $response_array['field3']
);

$firebase->set('users/' . $response_array['userID'], $data)
```

The `$response_array` is an array from an HTML form. `$response_array['userID']` is the Firebase user uid.

These rules work (no auth):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These, with auth, don't work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{ "error" : "Permission denied" }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that triggers the error message.

Comment: I've added the php code.

Comment: Are you sure `$response_array['userID']` has a value? For example, if you change the code to `$firebase->set('users/test', $data)` does it still give "Permission denied"?

Comment: I am sure, but I also tried with the test string you suggested. Still getting "Permission denied"

Comment: Good good. I just notice that you're not passing any sort of authentication token, which means your write is being performed as an anonymouse user. It looks like you'll need to call `setToken()` to set the user token. https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php#supported-commands

Comment: This was the correct solution. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank mentioned in the comments, you must call `setToken()` in order to authenticate all subsequent database reads/writes. To get that token from the client-side JavaScript and pass it to your PHP endpoint, you should use [getIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken) like so:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your PHP backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

With that `idToken` value, it looks like you can pass that along to the `firebase-php` library's `setToken` function:

```
...
$firebase->setToken(idToken)
$firebase->set('users/' . $response_array['userID'], $data)
```

As long as `$response_array['userID']` matches up with the uid of whoever makes that request, you should no longer receive the `Permission denied` error.